# How to scale two signals in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to scale a signal (`Sig`) to its reference (`Ref`) by calculating the scaling factor. Usually, I calculate the scaling factor by dividing `max(Ref)` by `max(Sig)`. But, it only works when both signals are starting from zero.

How to scale, if the signals are as follows:

```
Ref = [2 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 2 2 2 2];
Sig = [2 2 2 2 4 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 4 2 2 2 2];
```

This is my algorithm:

```
maxSig = max(Sig);
maxRef = max(Ref);
sf = (maxRef/maxSig);

figure('color','w')
hold on
plot(Ref, 'r')
plot((Sig)*sf, 'b')
legend('Reference','Signal')
grid on
hold off
```

**EDIT:** This is what I wish to achieve: The `Sig` has been multiplied by the scaling factor which perfectly aligns it with the `Ref`
[image]

*Note:* Both signals will always have the **same length** and there will be **no timelag.**

Comment: You have to subtract the minimum somewhere, but it depends on what you want to do. What would the desired output be in your example?

Comment: If tehre is no offset then they start at zero, right?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I think the OP means no x-axis offset

Comment: @LuisMendo Oh, I assumed that *no timelag* meant no x-axis offest

Comment: From your example it looks like you want to do `Sig_scaled = (max(Ref)-min(Ref))/(max(Sig)-min(Sig))*(Sig-min(Sig)) + min(Ref);` But since you provided quite scarce explanations, this involves a lot of guessing. For instance, is `min(Sig)` always equal to `min(Ref)` and if not what should be the behavior?

Comment: @Florian I have added some edits and yes `min(Sig)` will always be equal to `min(Ref)`

Comment: @user161816: So, does what I suggested work? If I apply it to your data I get the plot you suggested as desired output.

Comment: My solution doesn't need you to have the same minimum and is more universal. If your boundaries change, it will still be correct.

Comment: Neither does mine ;-) It's actually the same except that you scale by standard deviation whereas I scale by peak-to-peak (which I thought from the OPs question was the relevant metric).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a question exclusive to Matlab, so I will give a more general answer:
The usual way to normalize is to substract by the mean and divide by the standard deviation. As you do not want to modify the reference signal, this is my solution:

```
mRef = mean(Ref)
stdRef = std(Ref)
mSig = mean(Sig)
stdSig = std(Sig)
newSig = ((Sig - mSig)/stdSig) * stdRef + mRef
```

As was said in the comment, you can also scale with the difference between the minimum and maximum of both signals.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. How does it work? Can you please explain briefly?

Comment: If you normalize your signal and your reference, you should get the same output if they're linearly dependent. But you want to keep your reference intact, so you simply need to multiply by the stdRef and add the mRef on both to get back to your reference signal.